# How can I make an object to move horizontally or vertically in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to implement a String or TextView that moves from right to left. Thanks for your answers in advance.

Comment: Like an animation or do you mean like a marquee?

Answer (score 1):

I do things like this by handling my owning painting (onDraw()) and by using transfors to handle the shifting locations quickly.

Answer (score 1):

This animates a TextView from right to left.  I mostly copied this code from the Android API Demos app.  Note that animations should often be described in XML, and not in code, as this example does.

```
public class Main extends Activity
{
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Animation animation = new TranslateAnimation(100, 0, 0, 0);
    animation.setDuration(2000);
    animation.setRepeatCount(-1);

    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);
    myTextView.setAnimation(animation);
  }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/my_text_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I recommend reviewing the following documents on Android animations.

- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html
- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html